# JUnit の assertEquals で結果を比べようとしても型エラーになる

Tags: java, junit

AdministratorクラスのlistメソッドをJUnitを使ってテストしたいのですが、assertEqualsを使って結果を比べようとしても、型が違うと表示されてしまい上手くいきません。それと、リストの中身を全て比べたいのですが、それも良いアイデアがありません。どのように修正したらいいでしょうか？

```
@Test
public void listTest() {
    Object[] expectedEmps = new Object[];
    expectedEmps[0] = new Student("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "uni");
    expectedEmps[1] = new Student("2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "uni2");
    Administrator.add("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "uni", list);
    Administrator.add("2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "uni2", list);
    assertEquals(expectedEmps, Administrator.list(list));
}
```

Administratorクラスです

```
public static ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
public static ArrayList<Subject> listSub = new ArrayList<Subject>();

 public static void list(ArrayList<Student> list) {
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
        System.out.print("<Subject>: ");
        Administrator.listStr(Administrator.listCorrect(list.get(i).getID()));
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
public static ArrayList<String> listCorrect(String iden) {
    ArrayList<String> templist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < Administrator.listSub.size(); i++) {
        if(iden.equals(listSub.get(i).getID())){
                templist.add(listSub.get(i).getSub());
        }
    }
    return templist;
}
public static void add(String id, String password, String name, 
        String nationality,String address, String univeristy, ArrayList<Student> list) {
    list.add(new Student(id, password, name, nationality, address, univeristy));
}
```

Studentクラスです

```
public Student(String id, String password, String name, String nationality,String address, String university){
    this.id = id;
    this.password = password;
    this.name = name;
    this.nationality = nationality;
    this.address = address;
    this.university = university;
}
public String getID() {
    return this.id;
}
```

Comment: 型が違うからでは？
http://www.javaroad.jp/opensource/js_junit2.htm

Comment: タイトルには質問の概要を書くようにしてください。タグ以上の情報がありません。

Comment: @htb すいません、私が編集してしまいました……。

Comment: @u2298 回答者がコードを実行する手間を減らすために、エラーメッセージも質問文に書いて頂けると回答が集まりやすいと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
assertEquals(expectedEmps, Administrator.list(list));
```

`expectedEmps` は `Object[]` 型、`Administrator.list(list)` は `ArrayList<Student>` 型を返すので、明らかに型が違います。`assertEquals` は同じ型の同値を比較するものなので、この場合は `Object[]` 型同士または `ArrayList<Student>` 型同士を比較する必要があります。

JUnit でリストの中身を比較するのは確かにトリッキーです。もっとも単純なのは、リストをループで回して1つずつ比較する方法です。

```
List<String> expected = ...
List<String> actual = ...
assertEquals(expected.size(), actual.size());
for (int i = 0; i < actual.size(); i++) {
  assertEquals(expected.get(i), actual.get(i));
}
```

もしくは、より上級編としては、Hamcrest や AssertJ といったライブラリを使う方法があります。

Hamcrest の場合、`org.hamcrest.Matchers` クラスに以下のような比較用のメソッドが揃っています。いずれにせよ、リストの中身を全比較というメソッドはないので、何らかの工夫は必要です。  
http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html

- `arrayContaining(E... items)`
- `contains(E... items)`
- `containsInAnyOrder(T... items)`
- `hasItems(E... items)`

例えば、こんな書き方ができるでしょう。

```
assertThat(
    Administrator.list(list),
    containsInAnyOrder(
        new Student("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "uni"),
        new Student("2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "uni2"))));
```

（ただし、このコードは `Student` に `equals` メソッドが正しく実装されていることが前提です。）